# UE5 "Accessed None trying to read property PlayerInfo"

Tags: unreal-engine5

The project I am doing is based on the 8th video of a YouTube playlist: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcppbDG_4rMGt4DVTXjWUA7R3h302IzV&feature=shared

The problem:

```
Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property Player Info". Node: Branch Graph: EventGraph Function: Execute Ubergraph BP Third Person Character Blueprint: BP_ThirdPersonCharacter
Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property Player Info". Node: Return Node Graph: Get Health Bar Percent Function: Get Health Bar Percent Blueprint: HUD
```

I have tried a lot of things and I think the problem is that it is not giving me the `Health` and `MaxHealth` values because the life bar shows me 0.

[HUD Event Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNncL.png) [HUD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJxt.png) [Character Event Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU2Mg.png)

Comment: Very bad vay of asking question but, find the node in bp thats giving this error, check sourced target pin variable is under is valid section.